# How to setup global variables per Parallel.Foreach iteration?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm looking to find a way to setup a variable inside a Parallel.Foreach loop and make the variable easily accessible anywhere in the system, to avoid having to pass all desired values deep into the system as parameters. This is primarily for logging purposes

```
Parallel.ForEach(orderIds, options, orderId =>
{
     var currentOrderId = orderId;
});
```

And sometime later, deep in the code

```
    public void DeepMethod(string searchVal)
    {
        // Access currentOrderId here somehow, so I can log this was called for the specified order
    }
```

Comment: You should 100% pass the value in through the method(s).  That's far and away the best solution to the problem.  Avoid highly scoped state like the plague in general, but *even moreso* in a multithreaded context.

Comment: _to avoid having to pass all desired values deep into the system as parameters_ - do not avoid it. You will get in more trouble when use global variables which can be updated from different threads. Pass those values down to the "deep" methods, combine logically related and common values in the types.

Comment: You are looking for elegant way how to do that, but believe us, as you will learn and get to more complex stuff, you will appreciate more contained code, where each method will have some params and work on those params locally in sense of one iteration run rather than many threads working and accessing some parameter globally, it will be hell for complex code and all code tend to grow in that direction:)

Comment: I second Servy and Fabio's comments.  Method parameters and local variables are a happy, safe space you should love to be in in a parallel context.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, globally-scoped state for concurrently executing code is a poor design choice. If done correctly, you wind up with hard-to-maintain code and contention between concurrently executing code. If done incorrectly, you wind up with hard-to-find, hard-to-fix bugs.

There's not much context in your question, so it's impossible to suggest anything specific. But, given the description you've provided, the usual approach would be to define a class that represents the state for the concurrently executed operation, in which you keep the value or values that you want to be able to access at the "deep" level of the "system" (by this, I infer that you mean "deep" as in depth of call stack, and "system" as in the collection of methods involved in implementing this operation).

By using a class to contain the values and implementation of your concurrently executed operation, you then would have direct access to the value that's specific to that particular branch (thread) of the concurrently executed operation, as an instance field of your class, in the methods implemented in that class.

More broadly: a major tenet in writing concurrent code is to avoid sharing mutable data between threads. Shared data should be immutable (e.g. like a `string` object), and mutated data (like status values that you seem to be describing here) should be kept in data structures that are private to each thread.